# get_shape() and ndims for an image read through opencv

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, computer-vision

I read an image as follows

```
image_float = cv2.imread('/data/cat.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

The shape of the read image is `(1200, 1600, 3)`.

When this read array is passed to the following code  `if image.get_shape().ndims != 3:`, an error message will appear `AttributeError: numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute get_shape`

It seems to me that `get_shape()` and `ndims` are expecting a Tensorflow tensor. However, I read image using cv2 as the above. How to transform an image read by cv2 to a tensorflow tensor.

Originally, the image is read as follows

```
rl = ("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/"
       "First_Student_IC_school_bus_202076.jpg")

image_string = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)

# Convert image to float32 before subtracting the
# mean pixel value
image_float = tf.to_float(image, name='ToFloat')
```

Comment: OpenCV Python bindings use [numpy arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) to represent the matrices. The arrays have an attribute [`shape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html).

Comment: Yes, that's what I have been trying to do. But I am not sure whether numpy.ndarray.ndim is the same as ndims, I cannot find document explaining ndims in Tensorflow.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to a tensor first:

```
image_cv = cv2.imread('/data/cat.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

image_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_float, dtype=np.int32)
image_float = tf.to_float(image_tensor, name='ToFloat')
```

BTW why do you need the `IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag if it's a JPEG (with no support of alpha channel)?

You can also just ask TF to load the jpeg from that file:

```
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file('/data/cat.jpg'), channels=3)
```